# Android TableLayout расстояние между столбцами

Tags: java, android

В каждом tableRow находится 2 TextView.
Как можно сделать промежуток между самым длинным первым TextView и вторым TextView. И по нему выравнить весь TableLayout
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По рисунку нужно во 2 TableRow отодвинуть вправо 2 TextView

значение всех TextView устанавливается динамически

Answer (score 0):

Используйте в разметке параметы `padding` (расстояние между содержанием элемента и его внешней границей) или `margin` (расстояние от границы элемента до следующего элемента).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разницу между ними с примерами можно посмотреть на [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin).